# Show system bar(title bar) in AppCompat Theme Android

Tags: android, android-theme, android-appcompat

I am using AppCompat them from support V7. I am trying to make one screen full screen but with notification bar visible(solid color or transparent).
In styles.xml i have this:

```
 <style name="Theme.MyAppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
    </style>
```

And in the class, in onCreate() i have this:

```
super.onCreate(bundle);

getWindow().addFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Still, curious enough, the nativation bar still does not appear on it's own. Is there a property I should be using in the styles to make it correct? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Style.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"> </style>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
</style>
</resources>
```

In your manifest.xml

```
 <activity 
     android:name="YourActivity"
     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
 </activity>
```